# .htaccess pointing public_html to public_html/folder/ - Not Redirecting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to point maindomain to subfolder inside public_html

My root Structure

```
->public_html
->all files are here (index.php , contact.php , category-images, connect.php ...)
->subfolder (index.php , folder1, folder2 , images , conntect.php)
```

Now i want to open

```
www.mydomain.com to open the subfolder files.
```

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?my-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pom/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?my-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder/index.php [L]
```

It works for me ..

but when i open some pages from index file

my url goes http://www.my-domain.com/subfolder/productname.php
how to avoid the subfolder.

My Images should point to

www.my-domain.com/category-images/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in `/public_html/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!subfolder/).*)$ subfolder/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: But the images are not opening correctly..eg. www.my-domain.com/category-images/imgname.jpg ..is not found in the /subfolder/category-images/imagname.jpg

Comment: This is not changing image path. For that you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`.